# Node selector (affinities/tolerations) for Airflow base container

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I select k8s node for `KubernetesPodOperator` from `values.yaml` file and from DAG. It works well, but I would like to use different nodes per DAG but changing tolerations/affinities in DAG file would run base container based on settings from `values.yaml` file. Any idea how to control where base container runs from DAG file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using `KubernetesPodOperator` based task you can define affinity for that task:

- https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L116 - where the arg should be defined
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_modules/tests/system/providers/cncf/kubernetes/example_kubernetes.html#affinity - how to prepare your own affinity config that needs to be passed to `affinity` arg in `KubernetesPodOperator` (this file provides complete DAG example with task configured with custom affinity)

Comment: Hey! I'm doing this exactly - using `k8s.V1NodeAffinity` which works perfectly on tasks but ignoring base containers. Thus job is running on node defined in DAG and base container in node defined in `values.yaml` file.

Comment: Ah so you want to change affinity of `workers`, not `KubernetesPodOperator` spawned pods - that's my mistake. In this case you need to overwrite `executor_config` like that: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#pod-override or if you want this affinity to be for every task Airflow would create then this is the way to go: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#pod-override